# formsGroup ,datePipe error - Angular 14 ng serve

Tags: angular, forms, primeng

I updated my Angular 8 project to Angular 14. When I ran the project with the ng serve command, I got the following errors.
CommonModule is attached in app.module, but I couldn't solve the problem, can you help?

I deleted node-modules and package.lock.json and did npm but I still keep getting errors.

Angular CLI: 14.2.12
Node: 14.15.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.8

```
 - error NG8001: 'p-dialog' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-dialog' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-dialog' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.



 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'date'.
    
  .. class="ml-auto detail-text"><b>{{firstDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'}}</b></span>




-error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" [formGroup]="serachForm">


     - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'visible' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dialog'.
1. If 'p-dialog' is an Angular component and it has 'visible' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-dialog' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

 <p-dialog   [(visible)]="openPop" [modal]="true"





Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.12
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.12
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.12
@angular/cdk                    14.2.7
@angular/cli                    14.2.12
@angular/material               14.2.7
@schematics/angular             14.2.12
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.8.4


@NgModule({

  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    ...
    ],
    providers: [..]

})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: I think you need to import NgModule, FormsModule: import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';   "p-dialog" is from PrimeNG, maybe?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what you said in the NgModel import is attached , but I kepp getting errors. I started getting this error when I updated it to Angular 14.